# Failure to import pyOptSparseDriver

Tags: openmdao

I have installed OpenMDAO ver. 1.7.4 & successfully run several tutorial examples. However when issuing the command "from openmdao.api import pyOptSparseDriver" I get the response "ImportError: cannot import name pyOptSparseDriver".

I feel sure that I should be able to import pyOptSparseDriver (& that I have spelled it correctly). I have tried reinstalling OpenMDAO and this seemed to complete without error, but the problem persists.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [pyoptsparse](https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse) itself? That driver is only available after you install the necessary library.