# Using OpenAeroStruct with Fortran on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, openmdao

I need to run several analyses with OpenAeroStruct on Python 2.7.15 on a Windows 8.1 platform. These are quite computationally expensive so I'm aware that using Fortran could improve performances but on OpenAeroStruct main github page (https://github.com/mdolab/OpenAeroStruct) it is stated that "there is no documented Windows support for the Fortran code". However, I found this question here: [Failure to import pyOptSparseDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470576/failure-to-import-pyoptsparsedriver) that seems to be similar to my issue. If so, how do I install the pyoptsparse library ? I tried to copy the github in my python folder but still the driver seems not to be working.

Comment: Your question is not clearly worded. Are you trying to compile pyoptsparse or openaerostruct? Also you didn't provide any information on what your actual problem is. Could you post your actual error msg

Comment: @JustinGray I am running analyses with openaerostruct, and from what I understood the usage of fortran is linked with the usage of the pyoptsparse driver. In my code there’s a flag that tells me if pyoptsparse is being used; this keeps telling me it is not being used after I installed mingw for fortran compiling and put the pyoptsparse library mentioned in the link in my question above in my python27 directory

Comment: @JustinGray hey Justin, do you think anything can help me ? I really need to make my analyses go faster right now, I’d be so grateful if you suggest me someway to do that, thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

The usage of pyOptSparse and the usage of Fortran for OpenAeroStruct are independent of each other. Compiling and using the Fortran version of the code will give you the biggest performance gain.

However, as you've found, successfully compiling this Fortran code on Windows is not straightforward. I'd suggest one of three options:

1. Obtain a system with Ubuntu Linux or Mac OS to use the Fortran version of the code.
2. Attempt to use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) and a Fortran compiler to set up an environment within Windows where you could successfully install and run OpenAeroStruct's Fortran code.
3. You could set up an Ubuntu virtual environment within your Windows system, though this would take time and effort to set up and would be less computationally efficient than running it natively.

Comment: Thanks, I must exclude no. 1 as it’s really unlikely that I get access to a Mac or Ubuntu in the next days, also no.3 seems to be time consuming for me. I will try setting the environment within windows, could you help also with that if I have other issues ?

Comment: I haven't done it before, so I'd suggest giving it your best shot first. If you have specific questions, you could add a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: My opinion is that option 3 is the most likely to work for you. Setting up cygwin is not easy. But using virtualbox (https://www.virtualbox.org/) would allow you leverage lots of online tutorials on how to set up a linux vm on a windows machine. Then you can follow the existing OAS instructions.